# Django production: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: django, file, ioerror

In my Django app I have this kind of error: "IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'file_name'"

This is my code:

```
def record_export():
    for file_name, tab_name in tab:
        if len(globals()[tab_name].objects.all()) <> 0:
            f = open(file_name, 'wb')
            writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='|')
            for record in globals()[tab_name].objects.values_list():
                writer.writerow([unicode(s).encode("utf-8") for s in record]) 
            f.close()
```

In development enviroment all it's ok. I think that I have the permission.
In production I have: "IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'file_name'"
Do you know why?
Thanks for your help

Comment: I can assure you that the OS knows better than you do whether you have permission.

Comment: You're right. But why in development all work?

Comment: Usually development machines have different priveliges(sp?) than machines in production.

Comment: Look at what user the server is running as. Look at the actual permissions on the directory and file you're trying to write. Don't guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Djangos's runserver usually runs as root, this is probably your problem.

Your webserver needs rights to read/write the file. You can use `ls -l /your/path/to/file` to check permissions for a given directory. To change rights and owner, use `chmod` and `chown`.

If you are running a apache2 webserver your user and group is in most cases `www-data`.